# Xamarin Forms FlyOut Menu Not Showing on ContentViews Unless Access Through Menu

Tags: c#, android, shell, xamarin, flyout

I am using Shell via Xamarin Forms. 
I have noticed I can see the Flyout Menu (Hamburger Menu) only on the Contentviews/pages that is accessed via the Shell Menu itself.

However, if I access the view/page through a button on the view; then the Flyout Menu no longer appears

Any direction appreciated.

[image: Home page and I click on the Select a Service Button]

[image: Now the Flyout Menu does not exist]

[image: However if I go through the Flyout Menu]

[image: I see the Flyout Menu correctly]

Answer (score 0):

This is the design of Shell , Hamburger icon only shows on root page , if you push into next page(inside navigationpage) , the icon would change to back arrow which means you can click it to pop up to previous page .

Comment: Thank you for responding. My question is - if I go to another page through the hamburger menu, then whilst on that new page, I can still see the hamburger menu (flyout menu icon).I would no longer be on the root in that case. However if I navigate to another page through a button for example, then I do no longer see the hamburger icon or flyout menu...

Comment: when you go to page through hamburger menu , actually it is still on the root .